# Typescript: Trying to extract a complex type that’s nested within another type using [k: string]

Tags: typescript

I am looking to extract a complex type that is nested within a predefined object type.

```
// The 'events?' property is an extensive definition I would like to extract and use independently
type EventsCollection = { [k: string]: { name: string, events?: ComplexDefinition, desc: string }}
```

I have tried a number of ways to accomplish this, most have been similar to these, but none have worked so far.

```
type Events = { [P in keyof EventsCollection ]: EventsCollection[P] }

// and

type Events = { [P in keyof EventsCollection ]: EventsCollection[P]['events'] }

//and

type key = 'events'
type Events = { [P in keyof EventsCollection ]: Required<EventsCollection[P][key]> }
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying a bit too hard. You do not need a mapped type.

```
type Test = NonNullable<EventsCollection[string]['events']>
```

You just drill in with `[]` until you get to `ComplexDefinition | undefined`, and then wrap that in a `NonNullable` to remove the `undefined`.

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=14&pln=8&pc=31#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzAGwgDwCIQGYEsB2uwuc+UAvFAN4CwAUFFNnHAFxTABOArhPQL716oSFACiANwj5gAZ3jJUAY2KkK1eowDaAa3ayuBAOYBddrQaMo+AIYII+w-iMAaTVYhSZsgPzt4SKiYOAREJPhulowAJhCySo6cxu6CdKnC4NAAKnHA6gBypPncijYARqgAPJLScgrKqvhaBknOJloA5J61sh0mAHz0APRDVgB6PkA)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that any `keyof EventsCollection` (i.e. any `string`) is defined as having the same value types in `EventsCollection`.
Then you can use any key of that type to select the known `events` key of the inner type.

```
type Events = Required<EventsCollection[keyof EventsCollection]>["events"];
```

See it in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=13&pln=14&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzAGwgDwCrmgXigbwCgoSoBDALigDsBXBAIwgCcBuY0hqgZ2GYEtqAc3YBfQoVCQoAUQBuEasG7xkqAMbB+calDxFSUANoBrHn0FCAulQOHS1MggjmBw9vdIQFS7gH4qeCRUTGwPTygAEwhudVdLcJJRMQkpaHlFZT0oACUIAEdafmYISIAeDhIM31UNLR1TCBA4ADNZH2VaiE1taitCAD4jACJvTO5hq3ZCdR1eKDHfKmqs-UryKgBGABp1rihhgCZh3eTCIA).